# Когда в innerHTML писать кавычки?

Tags: javascript, html

Такой вопрос: если я напишу кавычки в этом случае, будет выводиться `а`не в качестве переменной, а в качестве буквы.

```js
const a = 5;
const out = document.querySelector('.out');

out.innerHTML = ('a');
```

```html
<div class="out"></div>
```

Если здесь я напишу код с кавычками, все сработает правильно.

```js
const out = document.querySelector('.out');

out.innerHTML = ('<button>Кнопка</button>');
```

```html
<div class="out"></div>
```

Какая тут логика? Получается, что если элемент является внешним по отношению к скрипту, мы указываем кавычки, а если внутренним - нет? Или как?

Comment: если чесно ничего не понял. Вы же передали строки просто в innerHTML, ожидали что-то другого?

Comment: есть такая штука как шаблонные строки

Comment: Скобки писать не обязательно. innerHTML просто строковое свойство. Есть небольшие исключения, например input - для них нужно использовать value

Comment: Если вы пишите скобки без указания имени ф-ции - это называется оператор скобки. Можете почитать как он работает. В данном случае `('a') ` будет эквивалентно `'a'`, потому что это работа оператора скобки (затрудняюсь сказать как это правильно тут назвать).

Comment: @nick_n_a да, оператор скобки влияет на порядок выполнения операций - приоритет. То есть innerHTML может употребляться **вообще** без круглых скобок и это не будет считаться ошибкой? Потому что я сейчас смотрю, любой пример отлично работает и без скобок. Выходит, что скобки употребляются только лишь для того, чтобы придать выражению в innerHTML бОльший приоритет?

Comment: Я не знаю кто придумал использовать скобки, на самом деле скобки повышают приоритет, но реально приоритет может быть увеличен только если рядом есть менее приоритетные операции. Т.к. таких нет то приоритет останется без изменений.  Возможно это "запутывание" (добавить побольше незначащих символов что бы было менее понятно что код делает). А возможно просто автору этих строк нравится такая форма записи чисто эстетически)))) Да, скобки тут лишние.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Логика очень простая. innerHTML может содержать в себе [html строку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_HTML). "а" и `<button>Кнопка</button>` это разные строки и представляются на странице разному.

> [HTML](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) (от англ. HyperText Markup Language — «язык гипертекстовой
> разметки») — стандартизированный язык разметки веб-страниц во
> Всемирной паутине. Код HTML интерпретируется браузерами; полученная в
> результате интерпретации страница отображается на экране монитора
> компьютера или мобильного устройства.

Comment: То есть если мы указываем кавычки "совсем тексту", то это будет распознано как просто текст. То есть "а" станет просто буквой. Это больше как я понимаю, на интуицию

Comment: innerHTML принимает html строку. и в данном случае да

Comment: @Eva Интуиция не при чем, есть всего одно железобетонное правило: Всё, что находится внутри кавычек - является строкой. Если при этом в строке содержится HTML-разметка, innerHTML вставит его как HTML...

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME ага, спасибо, такого типа железобетонное правило мне и было нужно услышать)